# Erroring with PetrelLogger.NewAsyncProgress

Tags: ocean, petrel

I am using the PetrelLogger.NewAsyncProgress which seems to work well.  However I can't figure out how to report an error with my task.  Once I Dispose of the NewAsyncProgress, it reports 'Success' for my task.

I have tried setting the ProgressStatus = -1, but that didn't make a difference.

Example:

```
 using (_asyncProgress = PetrelLogger.NewAsyncProgress("Doing Job", ProgressType.Default, (AsyncProgressCanceledCallback)AsyncProgressCanceled, this))
 {
    try
    {
        //Do Something
        _asyncProgress.ProgressStatus = 100;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Error happened
       _asyncProgress.ProgressStatus = -1;
    }
 }
```

So if an exception is thrown, the task manager result is Success 100%.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in Ocean at the moment. However, we have such requirement recorded, so it can be implemented in one of future releases

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I filed a support ticket and was told it would be considered for Ocean 2013.